# Android Studio shape xml file - no transparency in the background

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, styles, rounded-corners

My xml file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="50dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/quantum_grey"
        />
</shape>
```

Please help me :(

[image: Example image]

I gave the background color, But it was by no means transparent.

Comment: Can you add main xml code here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.